# Can we have an option to add more files in stack snippet like Plunker?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

If we go and look at the below `plunker` URL for an instance, we can see more files and a link to add a `new file`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

[image]

And also, we can link each from another file say for an instance, link CSS and JavaScript files in an HTML page and link another HTML page as a template file for [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS), etc.

Can we have a similar feature in the Stack snippet?

Comment: That feels like it would be extraordinarily prone to misuse.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

duplode [alluded to it in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339368/can-we-have-an-option-to-add-more-files-in-stack-snippet-like-plunker#comment420361_339368), but it's probably more concise to distill this point.

**This would be extraordinarily prone to misuse.**

Here's why:

- We already have users who believe taking a screenshot of their code is acceptable here.
- There's little reason to offload any extra duties to snippets, since they can easily reference external image and media files.  (I recall one user linking to Upular from Pogo as a demonstration.)
- This ***greatly complicates the snippet overall.***  You're suggesting that a user upload their entire project here, whereas we're interested in seeing the simple small nugget that really is their issue.  Small nuggets don't usually encompass several different files, and if they do, they should be refined *before* being posed to us.